# Query to get nextval from sequence with Spring JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a repository with which I am trying to get next value from sequence. The sequence name I need to be parameterized.

The repository query looks a like:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT ?1.NEXTVAL from dual;", nativeQuery = true)
String getSeqID(@Param("seqName") String seqName);
```

But, I am getting following exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: JPA-style positional param was not an integral ordinal
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterParser.parse(ParameterParser.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParamLocationRecognizer.parseLocations(ParamLocationRecognizer.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.internal.NativeQueryInterpreterStandardImpl.getParameterMetadata(NativeQueryInterpreterStandardImpl.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getSQLParameterMetadata(QueryPlanCache.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

Comment: Why do you needed nextval from sequence?

Comment: This is a functional need and the nextval from the sequence is required to be retrieved so the it can be used as a employee code.

Comment: No solution here highlighted how the sequence_name can be parameterized using a native query.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
package br.com.mypackage.projectname.repository;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<Myentity, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT SCHEMA.SEQUENCE_NAME.nextval FROM dual", nativeQuery = true)
    public BigDecimal getNextValMySequence();

}
```

Comment: Native query similar to this worked for me


```select nextval('sequence_name')```

Comment: is there a way to get sequence number without using native query?

Comment: How can I use a dynamic SCHEMA for the native query (different than the default schema).
For example in the case of an Oracle DB where someone wants to select a sequence of a different schema which might be dynamic.

Comment: What would be `Myentity` for the repository if the sequence is not linked to a table?

Comment: @MauricioToledo you can't . In the Id of MyEntity, you should specify the sequence. And the entity is a table. If you are using Oracle, maybe should find something in Spring JPA that can access this sequence

Comment: @MauricioToledo thinking again, maybe you can use the sequence, creating another method in some repository, but you must change the schema.sequence_name that matches the one that you want to use... i don't know, never did this, maybe works

Comment: @Hinotori I set the sequence as an SQL Native query in another repo. And, it did work!

Answer (score 5):

In PostgreSQL it is:

```
Long value = Long.parseLong(entityManager
            .createNativeQuery("select nextval('sequence_name')")
            .getSingleResult().toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tabelName")
public class yourEntity{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "yourName", sequenceName = "yourSeqName", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "yourName")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    protected Long id;
}

@Query(value = "SELECT yourSeqName.nextval FROM tableName", nativeQuery = true)
Long getNextSeriesId();
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT yourSeqName.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL");
return (java.math.BigDecimal)q.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: can't we use it without defining entity? By any way we can call it with dual within repository?

Comment: @AshishChauhan yes, you can use dual

Comment: do i need to invoke it with em?

Comment: Yes, em is Entity Manager

Comment: @AshishChauhan Please Accept the answer and vote up so others can get know about right solution.

Comment: Hi, I have faced similar issue like insufficient privileges while calling the sequence . How to solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EntityManager`:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("select seqname.nextval ...").getSingleResult();
```

Comment: The database I am using is oracle and the entity manager has been configured in another config class as a bean. The nextval(seqname) is giving error says unknown value. Can't I used anything with above approach within JPA repository?

Comment: I've edited the question with oracle dialect, I'm not sure, you can try putting it in `@Query`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue using the following code :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR code_sequence", nativeQuery = true)
public BigDecimal getNextValCodeSequence();
```

**NB:** you should replace `code_sequence` with your sequence name